# restart apache server by ssh command in perl php

Tags: apache, perl, ssh

I am trying to restart the Apache server through ssh command in perl - php.

Below is code I tried. It works through PuTTY. Though if I run through browser it does not run at line : `$output = $ssh->exec("systemctl status apache2")`;

```
use Net::SSH::Expect;
my $ssh = Net::SSH::Expect->new (
            host => "xx.xx.xx.xx", 
            password=> 'adsd#21', 
            user => 'root', 
            raw_pty => 1
        );
print("\n");
my $output = $ssh->login();
print($output);
if ($output !~ /Welcome/) {
    die "Login has failed. Login output was $login_output";
}


$output = $ssh->exec("systemctl status apache2");
```

The Error:

> "WARNING: terminal is not fully functional"

Comment: What do you mean by  _Though if i run through browser it does not run at line_ What errors are you seeing? What happens?

Comment: @Gerhard Barnard : i am trying to execute this perl file through php. So when i shell_exec the perl file it says "WARNING: terminal is not fully functional"

Comment: are you able to ssh manually from the source to destination without errors? What OS is the source and OS of the destination?

Comment: @Gerhard Barnard: yes manually i am able to restart the server without any errors. Source server and destination serveer is Ubuntu Linux.

Comment: Then why not just use a much easier method and ssh directly using ssh-keys?

Comment: @Gerhard Barnard: Why ssh-keys? i am able to login successfully. Though when executing the restart command i get the above error.

Comment: it is more secure and much easier to use. See answer

Comment: "command in perl - php" — What does PHP have to do with this?

Comment: @Quentin: i wish to run the script through browser. Though not giving desired results.

Answer (score 1):

Though Net::SSH is an elegant module, I would suggest using the system tools available to you by default.

You have ssh available and using ssh-keys are more secure, especially due to the fact that you currently display passwords in a script. If you are unsure of how to setup ssh-keys, let me know and I will add it to the answer.

Effectively your entire script can purely be:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $apache_status = `ssh username\@servername systemctl status apache2`;
   print $apache_status;
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try this way also.